# How do I joint iterate over 2 vectors by ref?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I'm trying to iterate over 2 vectors in one go using std::views::join

Here is what I'm trying:

```
std::vector<int> a {1, 2, 3}, b {4, 5, 6};
    for (auto &v : {a, b} | std::views::join)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
```

This fails to compile. Now, if I change the code to:

```
for (auto &v : std::ranges::join_view(std::vector<std::vector<int>> {a, b}))
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
        v++;
    }
```

it compiles and executes, however, the content of `a` and `b` is not modified.

How do I jointly iterate over a and b in a way where I can modify elements of a and b inside the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I jointly iterate over a and b in a way where I can modify
> elements of a and b inside the loop?

You can use `views::all` to get references to two `vector`s and combine them into a new nested `vector`

```
std::vector<int> a {1, 2, 3}, b {4, 5, 6};
for (auto &v : std::vector{std::views::all(a), std::views::all(b)} // <-
             | std::views::join)
{
  std::cout << v << std::endl;
  v++;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/69eEqGeYv)